# How to mount a preact-cli generated app to a custom div id?

Tags: preact

I am trying to mount the app generated by `preact-cli` to a custom `div id='root'` It seems like there is no config for such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also opt-out of preact-cli's automatic rendering - just don't export anything from src/index.js:

```js
import App from './components/app';
import { render } from 'preact';

// render into some specific element:
render(<App />, document.getElementById('my-div-id'))
```

Answered by [Preact author](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/issues/457#issuecomment-356632914)